# Where can I find syncing rules for dropbox?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I use my dropbox from multiple computers. After using dropbox for years, I am still not sure when exactly dropbox deletes (uploads) a file from (to) the cloud in a multi-device scenario. I'd appreciate if someone could provide a comprehensive explanation of this. My google skills have given up.

Thanks a lot!

edit:

### Scenario 1

Let X(a,b,c) and Y(a,b,c) be two machines X and Y with files a, b and c, such that both X and Y are connected and properly synced to a dropbox account D(a,b,c).

Disconnect Y from D.

Connect X to D.

Delete c from X.

Status-1 : X(a,b), Y(a,b,c), D(a,b)

Disconnect X from D.

Connect Y to D.

What should be Status-2?

X(a,b), Y(a,b,c), D(a,b,c)

OR

X(a,b), Y(a,b), D(a,b)

---

My next question will depend on understanding the answer to scenario 1.

Comment: Dropbox uploads, deletes, etc. it when it "Syncs", which is usually right after a change is detected.  Having said that, asking us to point you to documentation about a web service is off-topic (IMO).

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question. I understand the basics of dropbox syncing. But it's not clear to me what happens in complicated scenarios.

Comment: I don't think it's as complex as you think it is. :)  "Complicated scenarios" in what context?  Can you give an example?  When a change is detected by a client, the client syncs.  Newer files/changes win.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Please have a look at my edit. I have provided a scenario which I'd like to understand.

Comment: After the sync has happened on all devices they will all match - each containing the latest version of the files, regardless of where they came from.  PS: if you have a "next" question, please post it as a new question, and reference this one for context (if need-be).

Comment: So you are saying the final status should be X(a,b), Y(a,b), D(a,b)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: your last comment should be entered as an answer and the OP should accept that answer. This prevents this question from being deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scenario 1**

> Let X(a,b,c) and Y(a,b,c) be two machines X and Y with files a, b and
>   c, such that both X and Y are connected and properly synced to a
>   dropbox account D(a,b,c).

- Disconnect Y from D.

nothing changes

- Connect X to D.

X will fetch D's list of files to see if it has to sync

- Delete c from X.

C will be removed locally, push a new list of files to D and remove it there

> Status-1 : X(a,b), Y(a,b,c), D(a,b)

- Disconnect X from D.

nothing changes

- Connect Y to D.

Y fetches the list of files and sync, which is (a,b) so it will remove C

> What should be Status-2?

- X(a,b), Y(a,b), D(a,b)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I had a weird thing happen to me. Status-2 was X(a,b), Y(a,b,c), D(a,b,c). May be the clock of Y was wrongly set to future, resulting in that behavior.

Comment: That could be, indeed. It might also have had to do with internet connectivity from X which wouldn't push the changes to D, which then would apply to Y as soon as Dropbox is getting synced.